# Is there a way to receive DoWork EventArgs in RunWorkerCompleted?

Tags: multithreading, backgroundworker, args

I am using a BackgroundWorker for exporting some data to Excel.
I would like to open the containing folder after saving the file to a directory selected via SaveFileDialog.

I am calling the RunWorkerAsync(dialog.FileName) with the ExportFileName as parameter.

My needs would be to open the folder only when the file is successfully saved.
The right spot would be the Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) method. Is it possible to get the DoWorkEventArgs here or do I have to use a private variable to get my exportPath here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DoWorkEventArgs` object contains a property called **Result** which can be used to store any object you want.

This object is then passed to the RunWorkerCompleted function via the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`'s **Result** property.

You can use this property to pass your filename around.
eg.

```
void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = (string)e.Argument;

    //...
    e.Result = fileName;
}

void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = (string)e.Result;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Wow xD I should have found this too ^^ Thanks a lot mate